# Methods for Determining the minimal Width of Resolution Refutations for CNF Formulas

Tags: reference-request, sat, proof-complexity, csp, resolution

Recall that the **width** of a resolution refutation $R$ of a CNF formula $F$ is the maximal number of literals in any clause occurring in $R$. I am intersting in finding the minimal **width** of some certain unsatisfiable SAT formulas

I'm aware of two methods to find minimal **width** mentioned in academic papers:

- Ben-Sasson, Eli, and Avi Wigderson. "[Short proofs are narrow—resolution made simple.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2370656_Short_Proofs_are_Narrow_-_Resolution_made_Simple)" Proceedings of the thirty-first annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing. 1999.

which provides a method to determine resolution refutation width, primarily applicable to clauses and XOR SAT.

- Albert Atserias, Víctor Dalmau,
  [A combinatorial characterization of resolution width](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000007000876),
  Journal of Computer and System Sciences,
  Volume 74, Issue 3,
  2008
- A. Atserias, "[Unsatisfiable random formulas are hard to certify](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1029840)," Proceedings 17th Annual IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science, Copenhagen, Denmark, 2002, pp. 325-334, doi: 10.1109/LICS.2002.1029840

Atserias and Dalmau's method is comprehensive and encompasses a broader range of CNF formulas. They provide examples like pigeonhole and random SAT in their paper.

**My question:**

1. Is there any other methods to find minimal width?
2. For Albert Atserias' method, I am interested in exploring more practical examples or applications of this method. If you have any additional examples or references where this method has been successfully applied, please share them.

Answer (score 2):

Partially answering question (2), the Prover-Delayer game of Atserias and Dalmau can be interpreted as a more general "dag-like query complexity" specialized to CNFs. See e.g. [GGKS'18](https://dblp.org/rec/journals/toc/GargGK020). And the matching game in the paper of Atserias has connections to questions in network switching. See [FFP'88](https://dblp.org/rec/journals/siamdm/FeldmanFP88).